# Php undefine variable issue

Tags: php, mysql

I've a html form which is insert data to mysql database and then get those data with following php code (From **supplier_jv** table)

```
<?php
include("include/address2.php");
include("include/menu.php");
$uname_ad = $_SESSION['uname_ad'];  
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplier_jv WHERE jv_id = '$id'");        
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if($num == 0)
{
    echo "<p><font color=red>Accounts is emtpy</font></p>";
}
else
{
    $re_name = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    echo "<center><h2>";
    echo "<strong>Accounts of </strong>";
    echo $re_name['jv_name'];
    echo "</h2></center>";

    echo "<center>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' width='1000'>";
    echo "<tr/>";                   
    echo "<td><strong>Date</strong></td>";
    echo "<td><strong>Particular</strong></td>";
    echo "<td><strong>Folio(C)</strong></td>";
    echo "<td><strong>Folio(J)</strong></td>";
    echo "<td><strong>Debit</strong></td>";
    echo "<td><strong>Credit</strong></td>";
    echo "<td><strong>Balance</strong></td>";                   
    echo "</tr>";
    while($re= mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $day = $re['day'];
        $month $re['month'];
        $year = $re['year'];                    
        $parti = $re['particulars'];                    
        $folio = $re['folio'];
        $folio2 = $re['folio2'];
        $debit = $re['debit'];
        $credit = $re['credit'];
        $balance = $re['balance'];
        $b = $debit - $credit;

        $total_debit = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(debit) FROM supplier_jv");
        $re_t = mysql_fetch_array($total_debit);
        $t_d =  $re_t['SUM(debit)'];                

        $total_credit = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(credit) FROM supplier_jv");
        $re_t2 = mysql_fetch_array($total_credit);
        $t_c =  $re_t2['SUM(credit)'];                  

        $b = $t_d - $t_c;               
        echo "<tr>";        
        echo "<td>$day/$month/$year</td>";
        echo "<td>$parti</td>";
        echo "<td>$folio</td>";
        echo "<td>$folio2</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo number_format($debit);
        echo "</td>";                       
        echo "<td>";
        echo number_format($credit);
        echo "</td>";                       
        echo "<td></td>";                       
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#f3f3f3'>";      
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";
    echo "<td></td>";                       
    echo "<td><strong>Total Balance-</strong></td>;       
    echo "<td><strong>";                    
    echo number_format($b);
    echo "</strong></td>";                      
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</center>";                       
}           
?>
```

Well, After insert data then it's show:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: b in E:\xampp\htdocs\Accounts\admin\content
\supplier_account.php on line 108
```

But if i insert data in second time then it's OK!!.
Any idea or solution.
Thanks
shibbir.

Comment: Can you indent the code properly? It is not readable at all.

Comment: offtopic: `$balance = $re['balance'];` you don't have to do this, you can use `$re[balance]` inside double quotes...

Comment: Your error is funny as your code has only 85 lines and the error is on 108 line

Comment: Mr. @Somebody is in trouble this is a part of code...

Comment: Note that at line 77 (`echo "<td><strong>Total...` you are missing the closing quote) and also, if the query doesn't return a value, `$b` will never be defined (the second time you actually have data i guess so you enter the loop and define the variable).

Comment: Does reading the error message itself not explain it? "Undefined variable" means your variable is not defined! The most common reason for this is defining the variable inside a conditional block (`if`/`while`) and using it later, where it will not exist unless that conditional block was executed. That is exactly what is going on here, you are not defining `$b` if the `while` loop doesn't run at all. A decent IDE (like phpStorm) would highlight the usage of `$b` for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `isset` to see if it is set, not null and also avoid the `Notice: Undefined variable` error:

```
if (isset($b)) 
{
  // your code here
}
```

Where you have:

```
$b = $t_d - $t_c;
```

Make sure that there is some value coming up for `$t_d` and `$t_c`

Comment: yes, I checked this with isset(). It's show $b is not set. But i did this.. $b = $t_d - $t_c.